# Replace the 'echo-location' tag with 'echolocation'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The 'echo-location' tag is a typo. To my knowledge, there are no papers which use the word actually. The problem is SE forces you to use 'echo-location' instead. Could we replace the tag with the proper 'echolocation' tag before too many users get sucked into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As my first moderator action, I've renamed the `echo-location` tag to `echolocation`. It seems to have worked!

https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/echolocation

Comment: Did you "merge" the tag?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 5):

The issue that prevents creating the new tag [echolocation](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/echolocation) is that it "is too similar to" the existing tag [echo-location](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/echo-location).

[Diamond moderators](/help/site-moderators) (and staff with diamonds) have the ability to [rename tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731/1099857). While the site does not currently have an elected moderator, it will be an easy enough fix for them after some are elected.

In the meantime, there is no issue with continued usage of the tag as it can be quietly and easily fixed at any time in future (as long as someone reminds them of this).

The other option would be to remove the tag from [the only question currently using it](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/q/38/29), wait for the system to delete the unused tag ([at 3:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/1099857)), then recreate the tag with the correct spelling.